# Controller methods call Jasmine unit test suite with Karma in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am pretty new to Karma and Jasmine which I am using to write unit tests for my AngularJs application.

While running the test suite functions which I have called to initialize data in my controller is getting called by default. Is there any way to avoid this call while running the test suite?

Find the code snippet below:

`BaseCtrl.js`

```
App.controller('BaseCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Data', function($scope, $rootScope, Data){
    //initialize
    $rootScope.loader = false;
    $rootScope.data = false;

    $scope.init = function(){
        $rootScope.loader = true;
        Data.init(function(data){
            $rootScope.loader = false;
            $rootScope.data = data;
        });   
    };

    $scope.init();
}])
```

`Data.js`

```
App.service('Data', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        init:function(callback){
            $http.get('/url').success(function(response){
               callback(response);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

`BaseCtrl.spec.js`

```
describe('BaseCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $controller, $rootScope, $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    }));

    describe('Loader', function(){
        var controller, $scope = {};
        beforeEach(function(){
            controller = $controller('BaseCtrl', {$scope:$scope, $rootScope:$rootScope});
        });

        it('should be false by default', function(){

            // Check the default value
            expect($rootScope.loader).toBe(false);

            // Some code to determine the call, then

            expect($rootScope.loader).toBe(true);

            // Some code to determine the call is done, then

            expect($rootScope.loader).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When unit testing you SHOULD expect your calls to be invoked...that's the entire point.  that said, to prevent your calls from invoking $httpbackend you should use mock services instead and register them into the Angular injector

Comment: Hi @DavidL thanks for your comment, I understand your point, but is there any way I can track / watch the call in my test suite, so that I can test the data other scopes are affected by this call. I have tried using `spy(Data, 'init')` but it only tracking if I am calling the method from test specs.

Comment: Absolutely.  If you spy on a mockedData service that you inject into your test, you can can use `spy(Data, 'init').and.callThrough()` to force the spy to call your real method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `$httpBackend` to create a mock and return whatever you want.

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/url').respond({});
```

Comment: Hi [Dan] thanks for your answer, the data returned from service is not an issue. I have few scopes rely on this call which I am not able to verify as I don't have control over the calls. I have tried using `spy(Data, 'init')` but its only tracking if the method have called from test suite. Is there any way I can watch the init calls